# Custom Map Tiles in Google Maps Flash API

Tags: flash, api, google-maps

Is it possible to substitute your own tiles for google's map tiles in the flash version of the api?

I don't mean overlaying tiles on top of google's tiles but actually replacing them. We already do this using the V3 Javascript API, and would like to do the same for flash.

Answer (score 1):

i don't believe so, but you should download the API and skim thru the documentation to be sure.  if you're already knowledgable of the javascript API, you'll know exactly what to look for.  from what you describe, i'm not even sure i understand the difference between overlaying tiles and replacing tiles.

the most recent addition to the Google Maps for Flash API is Styled Maps and Elevation Services.

---

**Update**

if you are trying to avoid is seeing google's tiles quickly appear on the screen before your own, you could listen for the TILES_LOADED type of mapEvent, which will fully load your map tiles before showing them:

```
map.addEventListener(MapEvent.TILES_LOADED, tilesLoadedEventHandler);
```

Comment: Overlaying tiles would be placing your own tiles on top of Google's tiles, you basically see their tiles flash on the screen before your own.  The flash API docs do tell you how to make your own maptype, but the api seems to ignore what you give it, and I haven't found a working example online.

Comment: i've updated my answer.  if that doesn't help you could also try posting this and other questions about the Google Maps for Flash API on their forum: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/forum.html

Comment: Through trial an error I found the answer, and when I have more time I'll come back here and post it. But that's a good strategy to hide the google tiles, thank you